# Cancel Key before it is shown in NumericUpDown

Tags: vb.net, numericupdown

When I type a key inside a NumericUpDown, it is shown even if I cancel it, no matter which Key event I put it into.

I tried cancelling the key in all those events:
[events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9axzL.png)

It does cancel but I always see it for a second before it changes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it not sufficient to set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values?

Comment: If maximum is within 2 digits, I allow a 3rd digit to be typed and it then becomes the only digit in the control - it's a request by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve this requirement by simply clearing the `Text` property of the `NumericUpDown` instead of suppressing the third key:

```cs
private void NumericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (numericUpDown1.Value >= 10 && 
        e.KeyData is >= Keys.D0 and <= Keys.D9 or
                     >= Keys.NumPad0 and <= Keys.NumPad9) {

        numericUpDown1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Maybe you will have to check for additional conditions like leading zeroes, depending on the exact requirement.

Oh sorry, You want VB. Please, wait a moment...

... here is a VB version:

```vb
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If numericUpDown1.Value >= 10 AndAlso
        (e.KeyData >= Keys.D0 AndAlso e.KeyData <= Keys.D9 OrElse
         e.KeyData >= Keys.NumPad0 AndAlso e.KeyData <= Keys.NumPad9) Then

        numericUpDown1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

It also seems like `e.SuppressKeyPress = True` is working in `KeyDown`.

Comment: I have added a pair of braces to the condition in VB (C# doesn't require that because of the pattern matching).